# Would the Vulcan nerve pinch work on a Borg drone?

Tags: star-trek, borg, vulcan

If the Borg were to attack the planet Vulcan, could Vulcans incapacitate Borg drones using the Vulcan nerve pinch?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess it'd depend on the Borg in question - how much of their biologic nervous system is still in place/in use.

Comment: @VBartilucci, as far as I know their bodies still have nerves so I think that means they have a nervous system and it could be affected by a nerve pinch

Comment: I think that the Vulcans would be busy being assimilated/wiped out, so they'd have no time for nerve pinches...

Comment: @Loki, perhaps, but I would still like to know if it would work

Comment: @HRIATEXP - Try it and let us know.

Comment: My guess would be the pinch would work a couple-three times and then not.  Such a specialized attack would be adapted and compensated for.  New cyborg cable linkages and a nerve-rerouting and other argle-bargle would render the drones immune.

Comment: @Blaze, or maybe just a piece of armor or a shield.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### A nerve pinch would (with reasonable certainty) work on a humanoid Borg.

Tuvok is just about to "attempt" it in [*VOY: Unimatrix Zero, Part II*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unimatrix_Zero,_Part_II_(episode)) when he's interrupted. Given that he's the ship's Security Officer and has extensive hands-on knowledge of Borg physiology, it seems **very unlikely that he'd try it if he wasn't reasonably confident that it'll work.**

> **TUVOK:** *I will attempt to deactivate him.*
>
> [image]

And we see Spock doing it (successfully) in the Star Trek comic [Boldly Go #4](https://www.idwpublishing.com/product/star-trek-boldly-go-4/)

[image]

---

For the record, it doesn't work at all in the non-canon [Star Trek Online](https://www.arcgames.com/en/games/star-trek-online) game, showing effectiveness only on (some) entirely biological organisms.

[image]

Comment: That looks like the lesser known "Spock Lee" in that comic

Comment: @GordonBennett - It's not unusual for comic-book artists to make their characters unreasonably buff; https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOMCc.png

Comment: If we're talking about non-canon games, I seem to recall that the nerve pinch does work on Borg drones in [*Star Trek: Away Team*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Away_Team).